# Bootstrap based Navigation along with dropdown support to show evenly spaced nav using full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to use bootstrap to design a top navigation layout and I see that it defaults to left align. how do I get it to use full width of top?

Current
    https://jsfiddle.net/v2notb5n/

```
    <nav class="navbar">

<div class="fluid-container">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-inverse">
<li class="nav_page active"><a href="#" class="nav_txt"> Home</a> </li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" class="nav_txt"> Team <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">National</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Geo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Team Pictures</a></li>
                  </ul>
<li> <a href="#" class="nav_txt">About us</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>

</nav>
```

Expected result:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h8th.jpg

I tried something similar I found here [Bootstrap navbar justify / span menu items occupying full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601425/bootstrap-navbar-justify-span-menu-items-occupying-full-width)

but that didn't work for me.

Updated based on suggestions and answer here: https://jsfiddle.net/uahwra75/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the navbar stretch the full width, simply overwrite the `float: left` on `.navbar-nav` for medium screen widths and higher, with:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

I've created a working fiddle showcasing this **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/7u5hrkbb/)**.

Also note that you have incorrectly used the class `fluid-container` instead of `container-fluid`, which will affect your padding. I've corrected that in the fiddle abopve, and the snippet below:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none !important; /* StackSnippets require more specificity */
  }
  .navbar-nav li {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-inverse">
      <li class="nav_page active">
        <a href="#" class="nav_txt"> Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">National</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Geo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Team Pictures</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav_txt">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**EDIT**

To additionally ensure that the titles are centralised, you're looking to add a `width` to `.navbar-nav li` that is `100%` divided by the number of columns. COnsidering you have three columns, you divide by three:

```
.navbar-nav li {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Note that like the removal of the `float`, this should go inside of the media query.

I've created a new fiddle showcasing this **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/uahwra75/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your response and appreciate you catching the wrong fluid-container. I see the nav background stretches full width with your update. Now how do I make sure the nav elements are distributed evenly across that space?

Comment: For the `li` selector, add a `width` that is `100` divided by the number of columns in the navbar. You have three columns, so divide by three: `width: calc(100% / 3)`. I've updated my answer to cover this :)

Comment: Thanks. You are awesome! Btw, any idea why the 'Team' dropdown doesn't work for me? I tried copying one of bootstrap examples but didn't seem to work.

Comment: @user1413712 -- No problem! Your dropdown wasn't working because the dropdown `<ul>` is supposed to actually reside *inside* of the `<li>` that triggers it. I've corrected this in the above snippet, and also updated to include the full-width display change. Keep in mind you'll need Bootstrap's JavaScript file (and jQuery) in addition to Bootstrap's CSS file in order to get the dropdowns working.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the fiddle to reflect more or less what I wanted.
https://jsfiddle.net/uahwra75/1/
Appreciate your help again. Marked as answer.